# What is the Best Way to Get Text From Image with Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, text, tesseract

I want to get the text out of an image. I tried tesseract but I had issues installing it, so im wondering if I can get some help with that or another way to do it.
When I try to use tesseract it says I have no module names PIL? But I know I have pillow installed and i thought that was in reference to it.

Comment: Tesseract is the best.  I would solve whatever issue your having with it than try something else.  If your using windows and have access to WSL it's much easier to install on WSL

Comment: WSL? And well im stummped on how to fix it, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've provided a Colab solution since that will probably be useful to the most people.

Install tesseract in our Colab environment.

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
!pip install PyTesseract
```

Import libraries and mount our Drive

```
from google.colab import drive
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

Set our pytesseract path, read in source image from our Drive, show our source image, then finally convert the image to text.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.terreract_cmd = {
    r'/usr/bin/tesseract'
}

src = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/images/macbeth.png')
cv2_imshow(src)
output_txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(src)
print(type(output_txt))
print(output_txt)
```

[image]